# opencv cvtColor cv:Exception "scn == 2 && depth == CV_8U"

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using OpenCV 3.0RC1, but I upgraded from 2.4.10 in an attempt resolve this same issue, so the issue happens in both 2.4.10 and 3.0RC1.

The issue is I get an access violation when calling `cvtColor`.

```
std::ifstream file("D:\\raw-1920x1080.yuv", std::ios::binary);
file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
std::streamsize size = file.tellg();
file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
std::vector<char> buffer(size);
file.read(buffer.data(), size);

BYTE* data = (BYTE*)&buffer[0];

Mat image = Mat(1080, 1920, CV_8U, data);

cv::Mat yuvSource;
cvtColor(image, yuvSource, CV_YUV2RGB_UYVY);

return S_OK;
```

My image is a UYVY422 file with just raw pixels (no headers).

Any ideas why I would get this error?

Here is the exact error message.

```
C:\builds\master_PackSlave-win32-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:8538: error: (-215) scn == 2 && depth == CV_8U in function cv::cvtColor
```

Comment: try Mat image = Mat(1080, 1920, CV_8UC3, data);

Comment: Now I am getting this:

C:\builds\master_PackSlave-win32-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:8538: error: (-215) scn == 2 && depth == CV_8U in function cv::cvtColor

Comment: sorry, dont have much experience with opencv yuv representations...

Comment: CV_8UC2 did the trick!